# Different length to place in a dataframe from scraping

Tags: python, dataframe, selenium, xpath, python-requests

for scraping reactions for a post in a page facebook, i can scrape all the informations (comments, reactions, tags,...) but when i want to put them in a dataframe, a have an error (arrays must all be same length) which is normal because sometime there's someone who put only a comment and an another one only a tag, so i have lists with differents length. i think i can put a conditionnal if but may there another optimized solution...
for example len(tag) =2, len(usr) = 17, len(commentaire)=12.

thanks :)

```
        #imports here
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time
    from time import sleep
    from lxml import html
    import logging as log
    import pandas as pd
    
    #chemin de chrome et desactivation des adds automatique de FB anti scrape
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/Downloads/chromedriver.exe', 
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
    #open FB
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
    print ("facebook page log ok")
    sleep(1)
    #reperage de user et pass  (css_selector)
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    "input[name='email']")))
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    "input[name='pass']")))
    
    ##reperage de user et pass et click  (xpath)
    #username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@id,'email')]")
    #password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@id,'pass')]")
    usr=input('Enter Email Id:') 
    pwd=input('Enter Password:') 
    #enter données
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys(usr)
    print ("Email Id entered")
    sleep(1)
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys(pwd)
    print ("Pass entered")
    #reperage bouton log in et click
    button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    "button[type='submit']"))).click()
    print("login Successfully...")
    time.sleep(5)
    post = 'https://mbasic.facebook.com/AJSTunisie/posts/6452145678144265'
    #open the webpage
    driver.get(post)
    page = requests.get(post)
    df_comm = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['post_url', 'user', 'commentaire', 'tag', 'user_url'])
    page_count = 0
    while (True ):
    #scrape les reactions
            tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
            user = tree.xpath("//div[@class='eb']/div/h3/a/text()")
            commentaire = tree.xpath("//div[@class='eb']/div/div[1]/text()")
            tag = tree.xpath("//div[@class='eb']/div/div[1]/a/text()")
            user_url = tree.xpath("//div[@class='eb']/div/h3/a/@href")
            data= {'post_url':[post]*len(user), 'user':user, 'commentaire':commentaire, 'tag':tag, 
            'user_url':user_url}
            df_comm = df_comm.append(pd.DataFrame(columns = df_comm.columns,data=data))
            #Check if more reaction exist ("En afficher davantage" existe ou pas)
            next_link = tree.xpath("//div[@class='eb eu']/a/@href")
            if len(next_link)!= 0:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='eb eu']/a/@href").click()
                    page_count = page_count+1
            else :
                    next_link = ''
                    break
    df_comm =df_comm.reset_index()
    #df_comm.to_csv(path,index=False)
    driver.close()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should scrape all posts and later you should use for-loop to work with every post separatelly and in every post you should use relative xpath to scrape only information for this single post - and then you should create list with information for single post and add to DataFrame as single row. This way you can see if post has all elements and put default value for missing values. If you will scrape all post_urls, next all users, etc. then you don't know which post doesn't have tag and you don't know where to put missing values - and you can get first post with tags from second post.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in different way.

First you should find all comments - elements with text, user, tag, etc. - and next you should use `for`-loop to work with every comment separatelly. If loop you should use relavite `xpath` (starting at `.`) to get only information for this single comment. And then you can see if you have missing `tag` or other item and you can put some default value - i.e. empty string.

This way every comment will have all values so every row in CSV will have the same size.

This way also resolve other problem - in previous method you could get first comment with tag from second comment and you couldn't control it.

To make code simpler I put every comment on list of rows and later I convert all to DataFrame.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from lxml import html
import logging as log
import pandas as pd

#chemin de chrome et desactivation des adds automatique de FB anti scrape
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
#driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/User/Downloads/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

#open FB
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
print ("facebook page log ok")
time.sleep(1)

#reperage de user et pass  (css_selector)
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
"input[name='email']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
"input[name='pass']")))

##reperage de user et pass et click  (xpath)
#username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@id,'email')]")
#password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[contains(@id,'pass')]")
usr = input('Enter Email Id:') 
pwd = input('Enter Password:')

#enter données
username.clear()
username.send_keys(usr)
print ("Email Id entered")

#time.sleep(1)
password.clear()
password.send_keys(pwd)
print ("Pass entered")

#reperage bouton log in et click
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
"button[type='submit']"))).click()
print("login Successfully...")

time.sleep(5)

post_url = 'https://mbasic.facebook.com/AJSTunisie/posts/6452145678144265'
#open the webpage
driver.get(post_url)

all_rows = []
page_count = 0
while True:
#scrape les reactions
    page_count += 1
    print('\n--- page:', page_count, '---\n')
    
    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    
    # find all comments
    all_comments = tree.xpath("//div[@class='ec']/div")
    print('len(all_comments):', len(all_comments))
    
    # work with every comment separatelly
    for comment in all_comments:
        
        user = comment.xpath(".//h3/a/text()")  # relative xpath starting at `.`
        print('user:', user)
        user = user[0] if user else ""  # set default value
        print('user:', user)
        
        commentaire = comment.xpath(".//div[1]/text()")  # relative xpath starting at `.`
        print('commentaire:', commentaire)
        commentaire = commentaire[0] if commentaire else ""  # set default value
        print('commentaire:', commentaire)
        
        tag = comment.xpath(".//div[1]/a/text()")  # relative xpath starting at `.` 
        print('tag:', tag)
        tag = tag[0] if tag else ""  # set default value
        print('tag:', tag)
        
        user_url = comment.xpath(".//h3/a/@href")  # relative xpath starting at `.`
        print('user_url:', user_url)
        user_url = user_url[0] if user_url else ""  # set default value
        print('user_url:', user_url)
                
        all_rows.append([post_url, user, commentaire, tag, user_url])
        
    #Check if more reaction exist ("En afficher davantage" existe ou pas)
    next_link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ec es']/a")
    print('---')
    print('len(next_link):', len(next_link))
    
    if next_link:        
        next_link[0].click()
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        break

# - after loop - 

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['post_url', 'user', 'commentaire', 'tag', 'user_url'])
print(df)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
#driver.close()
```

Comment: thanks. i have a different xpath for comment `all_comments = tree.xpath("//div[@class='eb']/div")` and next page `next_link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@id='see_next_6452145678144265']/a")` . the relative xpath works without .

Comment: I think Google uses different classes and ids for different users to make code harder for scraping.